# How to remove all chrome data from a single device

Tags: google-chrome

I am leaving a job and handing in my work laptop.  I have resetted chrome to original status and logged out.  To test that all my data could not be accessed I tried to sign into a website.  All my passwords are still auto-populating.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Top-right, next to the vertical ... do you have a profile icon?

Comment: Did you clear your [browsing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJZgV.png)?

Comment: download ccleaner and run a clean with all check boxes marked under application / firefox. There you can choose e.g. passwords